# SignalR Clients.User() doesn't trigger the client

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-6.0

I use SignalR and .NET6. I have a three-way setup where I have a Server (C#), a Host (C#) and many Clients (JS).

My Server receives a Client Declaration from any client which connects it with a Host. The Client and Host don't actually know each other and only get to hear about each other through the server.

When my Client declares itself and gives an access token to be tied to a Host, I trigger the following two lines:

```cs
await Clients.Caller.SendAsync(ClientListenEvent.DeclareClientAck, (int)response, clientId);
await Clients.User(host.HostId).SendAsync(HostListenEvent.ClientJoin, clientId);
```

The first line lets the Client know that it is declared on the server successfully. However the second line never triggers anything on the associated Host. It simply gets emitted by the Server and then the Host never picks it up.

On the Host it's supposed to trigger this SignalR event:

```cs
connector.On<string>("clientJoin", (clientId) =>
{
    OnClientJoin?.Invoke(this, clientId);
    Debug.Log($"Adding Client: [{_indexToClientMap.Count};{clientId}]");
    _indexToClientMap.Add(_indexToClientMap.Count, clientId);
});
```

But it never does. I'm not quite sure why that is and I've been trying to debug this for a couple of hours today. Any help?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to check what's sent and received from the server in the Network tab. Are there any errors in the Console?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The Client, aka the one written in JS, works just fine. It gets the acknowledgement that it expects. It's the Host, written in C#, that doesn't ever pick up on the event that's supposed to be triggered with `await Clients.User(host.HostId).SendAsync(HostListenEvent.ClientJoin, clientId);`

Comment: You're using the wrong terminology so it's hard to understand what you're saying. The *host* is the application that runs the SignalR *hubs* and any other services. Ther may be many hubs in a single application. Clients run on Javascript (and other languages), connect to specific hubs and respond to notifications sent from the server. On the server side, how you send a message depends on whether you're inside a hub or not. Inside a hub you can use `Clients`. Outside a hub you need a hub context

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I specifically explained the terms I use and for what so hopefully shouldn't be that hard to understand. The Server only has a sinlge hub that gets used here so the calls I'm making can use the `Clients` object. What I don't understand is why the call to my Host from my server just doesn't get picked up using the `Clients.User()` call.

Comment: This is explained in [Send messages from outside a hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-6.0). What are you trying to do? What do you mean "trigger"? ` Clients.User(host.HostId).SendAsync` doesn't trigger something, it sends a message to a specific client. If you use Fiddler or another debugging proxy on the server you'll see the HTTP request

Comment: When you use different terminology from the product itself, yes, it's very hard to understand. Hosts don't run Javascript. Host in ASP.NET Core is the class that holds everything together, essentially the web app itself. `Clients` is only available inside a Hub, which, like a Controller, is instantiated in response to SignalR requests.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The terminology for my parts didn't actually matter in this case though...what mattered, as I found out, was that I used `User()` instead of `Client()`. So my application works as expected now.

Comment: User is the authenticated user, client the specific connection. Both calls send a message to a client. A user can have multiple connections. And there's no `host` inside a hub. So the terms do matter, and this question is still unclear. Whatever `host` is, it's not the Generic Host that runs SignalR. [There's no relevant `HostId` property in the entire ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?scope=ASP.NET%20Core&view=aspnetcore-6.0&terms=hostid)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure why you keep digging into the semantics, when that wasn't actually part of the problem at all. It is possible to not use the official nomenclature and still help people out :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the reason it didn't work was because I used `User()` instead of `Client()`.

So instead of `Clients.User(...)` it should have been `Clients.Client(...)` and similarly if you need to send to multiple clients, you use `Clients.Clients(...)`.

Turns out the User is an authenticated user in the server's own context, whereas the Client refers to connections.